How many processors are required to run ChatGPT?
I often find studies estimating the number of GPUs required to deploy a deep learning model. This paper, for example, estimates that ChatGPT would have required about 1024 GPUs in order to be trained over a month.
Why do they only talk about the number of GPUs? Why do they not mention CPUs or TPUs (which presumably were used since it is a deep learning model)?

no, most likely they used nvidia gpus... apart from that, they don't use CPU time because it probably highly depends on many other factors, such as RAM, where instead GPU have their own memory (and CPU are substantially slower than GPU for DL...)

GPUs have orders of magnitude more computational power for AI workloads, so CPUs are practically never the bottleneck. TPUs are an alternative to GPUs, and you can estimate the number of required TPUs from the given TFLOPs.
